# Gaussian eliminations with zeroes

Tags: matrix

A surprising amount of code I have searched up does not take into account zeroes in the matrix, instead relying on a ratio. I am trying to find the null space of a matrix mod 2.

I am trying to write code that can handle zeroes and free variables. Can someone verify that the will always work?

```
for each column
    if pivot exists
        swap row with pivot row
    else
        mark column as free and skip
    reduce column
        ...

set free variables to random numbers
calculate value of basic variables from free variables
```

The result should be the null space.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Random numbers are used because there are multiple solutions, and I want one. Zeroes are important because sometimes a pivot doesn't even exist, so I suspect that column is a free variable.

Comment: What language anyway?

Comment: @Evert I am working with C++. Alternatively I could use an external library to solve matrices for me.

Comment: But the library would still have to be interfaced with C++, right? Because I wondered if environments like R or Mathematica would be smart enough for this. You may want to tag your question `C++` as well, for better visibility (with a chance of downvotes for "what have you tried yourself"?).